# How to get last two characters before a letter in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this list:

```
532790M
47448M
378267M
467981M
53661M
583783M
524687M
390963M
493436M
185366M
150370M
497092M
3660G
568961M
152693M
254278M
353173M
```

I want to select only any last two digits before the letter "M" and "G"

Can I do it in SQL ?

Comment: Will the list always be a number followed by a single letter?  Also, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Access. Yes they all follows with M and G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select left(right(your_column, 3), 2)
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Left(text,n) returns the starting n chars of a string.  Right(text,n) returns the last n chars. Putting them together and you get;

```
Left(Right(text, 3),2)
```